# Any verification tricks for Mac OS X files?

Tags: macos, security, bash

Is there a good way to verify the various files in Mac OS X?

Ideally, one wants to verify system files in an installed system, but right now I'm curious about verifying the Yosemite installer.

If anyone still has a copy in `/Applications/Install OS X Yosemite.app`, then maybe they could produce a signature of some sort?

I produced [this hackish signature](https://pad.lqdn.fr/p/yosemite_shasum.txt) with these commands :

```
find '/Applications/Install OS X Yosemite.app' -type f -print0 | \
  xargs -0 shasum -a 256 > yosemite_shasum.txt
gpg --clearsign yosemite_shasum.txt
```

A `diff` command should pick up any files that're different in different people's installer, even if you drop the second `gpg` command.  I assume nobody sees any differences at this moment in time?

Comment: If you get the Installer from Apple (via the App Store), there shouldn't be a need to verify...

Comment: The installer (and any app from the App Store) is already Code Signed and any modifications to the files will result in the app not launching. Disk Utility launched from the Recovery partition is useful to check the OS files for modification.

Comment: There are adversaries who possess Apple's private keys both for code signing and TLS, and can win packet races, patrix.  And said adversaries targets sys admins who work in the telecom sector.  https://firstlook.org/theintercept/2014/03/20/inside-nsa-secret-efforts-hunt-hack-system-administrators/  Recall "every attempt to implant iOS [by QUANTUMTHEORY] will always succeed” :   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vILAlhwUgIU#t=44m45s